# Creating a quiz app when user selects wrong answer it gives color red and also highlights correct answer with green color

Tags: java, android

I am creating a quiz app in android studio using java i want to add a feature that if user select wrong option it gives red color and also it tells the correct answer by highlighting correct answer color green and switch to next question.
And when user selects correct answer it gives green color and switch to next question.

Here is my code

```
  option1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(option1.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    mScore++;
                    scores.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                    updateQuestions(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                }
                else if(option2.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else if(option3.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else if(option4.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }

                else{

                    gameOver();
                }

            }
        });
        option2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(option2.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    mScore++;
                    scores.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                    updateQuestions(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                }
                else if(option1.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else if(option3.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else if(option4.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else{
                    gameOver();
                }

            }
        });
        option3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(option3.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    mScore++;
                    scores.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                    updateQuestions(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                }
                else if(option1.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else if(option2.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else if(option4.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else{
                    gameOver();
                }

            }
        });
        option4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(option4.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    mScore++;
                    scores.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                    updateQuestions(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                }
                else if(option1.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else if(option2.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else if(option3.getText()==mAnswer){
                    option3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else{
                    gameOver();
                }

            }
        });
    }
    private void updateQuestions(int num){

        question.setImageResource(mQuestions.getQuestion(num));
        option1.setText(mQuestions.getChoice1(num));
        option2.setText(mQuestions.getChoice2(num));
        option3.setText(mQuestions.getChoice3(num));
        option4.setText(mQuestions.getChoice4(num));

        mAnswer= mQuestions.getCorrectAnswer(num);
    } private void gameOver(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Game Over! Your Score is " +mScore + " points.")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("NEW GAME",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("EXIT",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is your problem ?

Comment: i have mentioned above

Comment: i want when user click on wrong option button button color chages to red and it also highlights correct button with green color

Comment: @KashafAli are you asking for someone to develop a feature for you?